# How to retrieve the return code of a command in a short-circuit expression

Tags: bash, exit-code, short-circuiting

After an expression:

```
command1 | command2
```

I can retrieve the first commands exit status through `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`

Is there an equivalent for expressions in the form:

```
command3 && command4 || command5
```

I would like to retrieve the exitcode of command3:

```
command3 && command4 || command5
retval=${SHORTCIRCUIT[0]}     # how to get this value?
```

Preferably without creating temporary files.

Comment: Given that here `command4` is using the return status of `command3`, I'd definitely like to see an answer for this question as well, without a work around like `command3; ST=$?; [[ $ST -eq 0 ]] || command4`

Comment: Also, these workarounds tend to break when using `set -e`.

Comment: Alter your question to `command3 && command4 || command5` and `status of command3`, to make the question crystal clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating devnull's approach leads to

```
{ c3=0; command3 || c3=$? && false; } && command4 || command5
echo $c3
```

.
Because every `command` can be replaced by

```
{ c=0; command || c=$? && false; }
```

(provided that `c` is initially unset if executed conditionally), this is easily extensible.